# How can I select a this DOM element using a CSS selector in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: css, google-tag-manager, pseudo-class

I have created a variable in Google Tag Manager where the variable type is DOM Element and the selection method is CSS Selector. I am trying to select a line of text from a page but getting a null result each time.

Below is the HTML code from which I am trying to select text:

```
<div class="school-header-right-column">
<h2 id="school-name">&#8216;Iolani School</h2>
<ul class="top_header_ul">
<li id="school-type">Trường tư</li>
<li id="school-level">THPT</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried selecting using the following different variations in the Element Selector field of the DOM Element variable in Google Tag Manager, but after debugging, all of these different variations return "null".

- `#school-type`
- `.top_header_ul > li:first-child`
- `.top_header_ul > li:nth-child(1)`

I've also tried selecting other text in this code block, such as the school-name or school-level, and it returns null each time.

I do know that there is a CSS pseudo-class being inserted into the `<li>`, could that be causing a problem? The psuedoclass is `::after` ... however, that shouldn't affect things if I try to select the text within the `<h2>` tags, right? Yet I still get null if I try the selector `.top_header_ul > h2`

Thanks in advance. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Your selectors are all correct. That means the problem comes from something else.

Comment: Can you share more on what you did in GTM? Maybe you use the `page_view` trigger which is too fast for the dom rendering. Or maybe something else not right in the Google Tag Manager

Comment: Thanks InSync -- the problem was in GTM itself. I had set an attribute name for the variable, when I should have left it blank. Solved. Thank you